# Objective C - Getter and setter properties for enum

Tags: iphone, objective-c, enums, properties

I am a complete newbie at Objective-C. I have an enum as follows:

```
typedef enum _XLBadgeManagedType {
    XLInboxManagedMethod = 0,
    XLDeveloperManagedMethod = 1
} XLBadgeManagedType ;
```

I want to have getter and setter methods for it, such that if something happens, I set `XLInboxManagedMethod` to 1. How would I go about doing it?

Comment: You are confused to what an `enum` or `enumeration` is.  This is a static, and constant list of values.  If you want to set a property, use a property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is just defining an enum type. It's a static, compile-time constant that is not changed. You use enums by declaring an instance of one, then changing it to one of the constant values you defined. If your enum looks like:

```
typedef enum _XLBadgeManagedType {
    XLInboxManagedMethod = 0,
    XLDeveloperManagedMethod = 1
} XLBadgeManagedType;
```

Then your property could look like:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) XLBadgeManagedType myEnum;
```

And its use may look like:

```
- (void)someMethod {

    self.myEnum = XLInboxManagedMethod;
    self.myEnum = XLDeveloperManagedMethod;
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not change the values of enums. They stay as they are.

Answer (score 0):

They are symbolic constants. You can not change it.