# Can I use an enum as a property in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, properties, enums

I saw it is customed to use a boolean property as a flag. something like that:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL commaAlreadyIntroduced;
```

I need something like that but with at least 3 or 4 states.

Can I use an enum?

The standalone enum should look like:

```
typedef enum stackState{
    empty, oneOperand, operandAndOperator, fullStack
}stackState;
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863167/objective-c-getter-and-setter-properties-for-enum

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126177/using-a-typedef-enum-in-my-object-class

Comment: You should really be using typedef NS_ENUM.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, it's not a problem:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) stackState yourIvar;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) enum stackState stackStateVar;
```

Without 'enum' added, my unit tests kept showing errors.

Comment: this post has been here for 4 years, i don't think any new answers would get much attention.

Comment: Could be because you don't use typedef or NS_ENUM for your enum.

Answer (score 3):

@property (nonatomic, assign) enum stackState yourIvar;

(was getting errors until I added *enum*)